# Elasticsearch - Search for a range of dates but exclude dates different from placeholder dates

Tags: elasticsearch

I am looking for a way to search a date in Elasticsearch but I want to get only exact matches or matches with placeholder dates that are within a range.
The problem is that I want to **exclude dates that are obviously different from the one I am looking for**.

Example:

- Search for 1992-07-02.
- In the boolean query I set a match query looking for the exact date.
- Then I set, as a must clause, a range query using the year of birth

```
{
                "range": {
                  "date": {
                    "gte": "1992||-2y/y",
                    "lte": "1992||+2y/y",
                    "format": "yyyy"
                  }
                }
              }
```

The I want to exclude dates like 1991-06-29 which is in the range but it's not a placeholder date like 1991-01-01 or 1992-01-01.

Is there a way to do that?

Full query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "date": {
              "query": "1992-07-02"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "date": {
              "gte": "1992||-2y/y",
              "lte": "1992||+2y/y",
              "format": "yyyy"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Can you show the full query?

Comment: Try filter instead of must, because `must+should` is not the same as `filter+should`

Comment: I tried that but the problem remains. The filter return all the dates between two years but I want to have only placeholder dates and the date I'm looking for and no other dates.